# How-to configure Spring data source to avoid participation in transaction synchronization?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I'm observing seemingly weird behavior related to how Spring handles operations with multiple data sources, especially participation in transaction synchronization.

My Spring context has two data sources configured:

1) dataSource1 - MySQL database

2) dataSource2 - Apache Impala database

Both data sources have a jdbc template configured for them. Additionally dataSource1 has a transaction manager configured. dataSource2 has no transaction manager configured (Apache Impala does not have transactions by design, it just happens to expose SQL-like querying functionality via JDBC connector).

I'm using this configuration in a spring-batch application - dataSource1 and its transactionManager is set to be used to store data related to spring-batch job meta-info.

Next I have a spring-batch job configured with a single custom Tasklet step. In this step I'm accessing dataSource2 via its jdbc template. And this is where the problem occurs - to my surprise connection to dataSource2 starts to participate in a transaction synchronization.

```
2018-06-06 10:41:08,179 DEBUG [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Registering transaction synchronization for JDBC Connection
```

I understand that upon a start of a spring-batch step a transaction related to dataSource1 is started however why should dataSource2 be anyhow involved in that?

A negative side-effect is that once connection to dataSource2 starts to participate in transaction synchronization the connection is not closed after e.g. jdbcTemplate.execute(...) command completes. Essentially what I'm observing is that open connections to dataSource2 are closed only when the outer transaction completes.

**Is there a way to configure Spring context and dataSource2 to not participate in a transaction synchronization?**

Configuration

```
<bean id="dataSource1" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource1JdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource1">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="..."/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    </property>
    <property name="sharedCacheMode" value="DISABLE_SELECTIVE"/>
</bean>



<bean id="dataSource2" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource2JdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource2"/>
</bean>
```